# How do I look into a Starcraft 2 replay?

Tags: php, parsing, replay

I am interested in building a parser for my own enjoyment using PHP. What do I need to know? What suggestions would you have for me? How do I even open a Starcraft 2 replay using PHP?

Comment: Try gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not out of laziness, but could a mod move this?

Comment: Closing already? I seriously am trying to learn here and I have no idea or direction, it would be nice if someone could show me the direction at least.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The SC replay file is actually an MPQ archive file.  This MPQ archive contains a few different files (like a .zip file).

Inside this archive are separate files for each of the types of data in the MPQ archive.
(For example there is one file for  game events and another for UI events).

There is a fair amount of documentation online about how to deal with MPQ files.  Now, the individual files within the MPQ is a bit trickier.

If you want to get the information from the replay (who the players were and what map they played on) you can use these tools.  (I'm assuming a Unix like web server).

1) Download and build libmpq and mpq-tools (https://libmpq.org/ )

2) Run the following scripts

You can run these from a system() call and then run a few split commands to get the players and the race.

Save this as info.sh.  Run it like a command shell and pass in the replay file as an argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Save this file as info.sh

# This extracts the individual files from the MPQ archive (the replay
# file)


mpq-extract -e $1 > /dev/null
cat file000000.xxx | strings | ruby info.rb
```

Here is a ruby script.  Save this as info.rb

```
# This *kinda* extracts the file info from a header file.  I don't
# really know how it works yet, so I'm just extracting strings.
#
# Save this file as info.rb

lines = STDIN.readlines
puts "%s:%s|%s:%s" % [(lines[0].strip), (lines[1].strip), (lines[2].strip), (lines[3].strip)]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/phpsc2replay/

I think it may be exactly what you are looking for.  I certainly wish I had found it a month ago.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I even open a Starcraft 2 replay using PHP?

With any of PHP's filesystem functions http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Since most SC2 replays seem to be fairly small in size you could probably get away with `file_get_contents()` to retrieve the entire file as a string.